# How to read string followed by character in c?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
   char *str, ch;
   int count = 0, i;

   printf("\nEnter a string : ");
   scanf("%s", str);

   printf("\nEnter the character to be searched : ");
   scanf("%c", &ch);

   for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      if (str[i] == ch)
         count++;
   }

   if (count == 0)
      printf("\nCharacter '%c'is not present", ch);
   else
      printf("\nOccurence of character '%c' : %d", ch, count);

   return (0);
}
```

while i executing this code the string is taken after that it will not taking any characters and showing results.

Comment: 1) `str` does not point to a valid area. 2) `scanf("%c", &ch);` --> `scanf(" %c", &ch);`

Comment: `str` is an uninitialised pointer. Using it in `scanf` results in Undefined Behaviour. Need to allocate a buffer and assign to `str` first.

Answer (score 1):

Your code might crash (happened to me when verifying it on my machine) because you did not allocate space for `str`...
you should change `char *str, ch;` to something like `char *str = malloc(100), ch;`

Also, change `scanf("%c", &ch);` to `scanf(" %c", &ch);` to resolve your problem. This happens because when you enter your string, you end it with enter, and that enter is consumed by your next `scanf(%c)` and so, your second `scanf()` only reads the enter instead of reading the char you intend. `scanf(" %c", &ch);` will ignore all whitespaces, including the previously entered enter :-) and wil allow your char to be processed

Comment: You might like to add that `scanf()` as shown might still overflow any buffer provided.

Comment: @alk do you mean in case that the input string is larger than the buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Always write scanf like this, to read the previous newline character:

```
printf("\nEnter the character to be searched : ");
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

OR

use `getchar()`

```
printf("\nEnter the character to be searched : ");
getchar();
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a max length would be the simplest way to solve this. Insted of using scanf, I would recomend using fgets as done below. It is much more failsafe since you can define the max number of characters to be read.
[Tutorialspoint's explanation of fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 100

int main() {
   char str[MAX_LENGTH], ch;
   int count = 0;

   printf("\nEnter a string : ");
   fgets(str, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);

   printf("\nEnter the character to be searched : ");
   scanf("%c", &ch);

   ...

}
```

Comment: Be aware that *using this appraoch* `str` *now* most likely is ending with a new-line character (`\n`).

Comment: fgets puts a "\0" at the last position automatically.